# How do you suppress unwanted decimal places in a kendoNumericTextBox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid with many kendoNumericTextBoxes. I only want to allow whole numbers.
The following code does round to the nearest whole number, however, it still displays ".00" after the whole number. I want to only display the whole number: "$12" instead of "$12.00" in the cells.

The code:

```
.kendoNumericTextBox({
    spinners : false,
    format: "c0",
    decimals: 0
});
```

Comment: Your code appears to work fine for a standalone numeric text box so perhaps it is to do with being within a grid. Can you confirm if that is the case for you as well? Any chance you can put together a simple dojo to recreate the problem?

Comment: You're right - the numeric textbox was formatting correctly, but it was the grid cell displaying the decimal places. The problem was that the grid column itself was formatted: format: "{0:c}", but needed to be format: "{0:c0}". Thanks for your time helping to troubleshoot.